# How to outline a java.awt.Shape with an outline that fades towards the outside

Tags: java, awt, java-2d

What I am wanting to is draw some Shape (could be any type of Shape) in Java2d such that inside of its border it is all one color, but at the Shape's edge, the color fades to whatever color was behind the Shape over the thickness of the border that I want to apply to it.

The only way I can come up with to do this is to repeatedly draw the border with increasing transparency values starting at width 0 and fully opaque and going to however wide I want the border to be and fully transparent in increments of 1 unit of width.  This is a less than ideal solution, however, because it has rapidly deteriorating performance as the scale is increased and the border needs to be thicker. What I am ideally after is a solution where performance does not degrade linearly with the width of the intended rendered border, as my current naive approach does.

Comment: I don't think you can really achieve what you're trying with the default API.  Generally speaking a gradient fill (which is what I thought of first), works on an area, not a shape.  You could play around with the anti-aliasing values instead